# Storing a Base 64 String in NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, nsuserdefaults

I am working on some code that I inherited from a programmer who is no longer with my company.  In this code, a few images are encoded as base 64  string, then subsequently stored in `NSUserDefaults` inside a `NSDictionary`.  The issue I am having is if the application has been killed (i.e. thorugh the mulitasking UI), the dictionary containing the data does not seem to load.

Are Base 64 strings considered a property list objects in Objective-C?

I realize this is ***NOT*** the ideal solution for storing data on disk, but this is what I have to work with for the immdeiate future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do they show up in the application's plist as `string` or `data`? If the latter, they're encoded `NSData` objects; try using `objectForKey:` and then `-[NSImage initWithData:]`.

Comment: That is how I am setting the value.  However, they are not being stored as an image later, the data will be sent as part of an http post.

Comment: Base 64 strings are just strings, so they are property list objects, if that's all you needed to know…